# Android: No content provider when trying to get saved Image URI

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

I have a Fragment that should: Open camera, show the photo taken, save the URI path (sqlite) and show that photo again if I return to the fragment (getting the saved URI path)

**My problem** is when I'm trying convert the saved URI Path to Bitmap. **This error** happens:

```
FileNotFoundException: No content provider: 
/external_files/Pictures/JPEG_20201001_234640_3080292023640638214.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

**My Fragment:**

```
class TakePictureFragment : Fragment() {
    
    private var photoURI: Uri? = null
    private var imageView: ImageView? = null
    
    private val itemId by lazy {
        arguments?.getLong("ITEM_ID")
    }
    
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_take_picture,container,false)
        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.view_show_photo)

        val button: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.open_camera)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            openCamera()
        }
        return view
    }
    
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val photo = PhotoDAO.get(itemId)
        if(photo != null) {
            photoURI = Uri.parse(photo.photoURI)
            showPhoto()
        }
    }
    
    private fun openCamera() {
        val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        var photoFile: File? = null
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            Log.i("ERROR", "IOException")
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    context.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
                    photoFile)
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1)
        }
    }
    
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
        val storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir) 
        // The shame problem happens if I return: return File(storageDir, "$imageFileName.jpg")
    }
    
    private fun showPhoto() {
        val imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, photoURI)
        imageView?.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
    }
    
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            showPhoto()
        }
    }
    
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == R.id.actionNext) {
            
            PhotoDAO.save(itemId, photoURI?.path)
            
            // Go to next Activity / Fragment
            
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

PS: The URI Path String is saving and getting correctly from the "PhotoDAO"

PS2: If I use `Uri.fromFile(File(photo.photoURI))` instead `Uri.parse(photo.photoURI)` the error is just "No such file or directory"

Comment: You should not save/use uri.getPath() but uri.toString() and then not use the File class. Uri.toString() is your content scheme.

Comment: Further you can make it yourself easier to store photoFile.getAbsolutePath() instead. Then you can use the File class too.

Comment: This error happens "Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: / (Permission denied)" When I Try to "Uri.fromFile(File(path))"

Comment: Do not use Uri. Only path and File. And you should have told the value of path of course. Should we guess that all?

Comment: It works with the asolutePath... I'll post the final working code here later. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It works like this:**

```
class TakePictureFragment : Fragment() {

    private var photoURI: Uri? = null
    private var photoPath = ""
    private var imageView: ImageView? = null

    private val itemId by lazy {
        arguments?.getLong("ITEM_ID")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_take_picture,container,false)
        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.view_show_photo)

        val button: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.open_camera)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            openCamera()
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val photo = PhotoDAO.get(itemId)
        if(photo != null) {
            photo_description.setText(photo.description)
            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    context.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
                    File(photo.path))
            showPhoto()
        }
    }

    private fun openCamera() {
        val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        var photoFile: File? = null
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            Log.i("ERROR", "IOException")
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    context.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
                    photoFile)
            photoPath = photoFile.absolutePath
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1)
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
        val storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File(storageDir, "$imageFileName.jpg")
    }

    private fun showPhoto() {
        val imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, photoURI)
        imageView?.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            showPhoto()
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == R.id.actionNext) {
            
            PhotoDAO.save(itemId, photoPath)
            
            // Go to next Activity / Fragment
            
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Thanks @blackapps for the "getAbsolutePath" tip in the comments.